# Error Action App\Http\Controllers\bodegaController@sacar not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo este error

```
 Action App\Http\Controllers\bodegaController@sacar not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bodega\resources\views\bodega\index.blade.php)
```

En mi ruta web.php

```
Route::get('sacar','App\Http\Controllers\bodegaController@sacar')->name('sacar');
```

Controller

```
public function sacar($id)
{
    $bodega = bodegaModel::find($id);
    return view('bodega.sacar', compact('bodega'));
}
```

Y en el blade donde llamo la accion

```
<td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{{action('bodegaController@sacar', $bodegas->codigo)}}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
            </td>
```

No se cual es el error ya que esta todo definido y si vemos el error me lo muestra en el controlador pero ya funcion esta definida.

Gracias espero su ayuda.

Comment: Pues esa es la accion que llamo para el controlador y le paso el codigo que viene siendo como el id, de hecho tengo otra funcion edit que es exactamente igual a esta solo que edit me edita todos los campos y la nueva que intento implementar solo va a editar 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comentarios:

1. Tu ruta esta incompleta, pues como notas cuando la defines en el archivo web.php solo es `sacar` pero cuando la usas en la etiqueta `a` espera un valor dinámico entonces debería quedar de esta forma:

   ```
   Route::get('sacar/{codigo}','bodegaController@sacar')->name('sacar');
   ```
2. No necesitas declarar el namespace completo al momento de invocar tu controlador, desde que en Laravel (al menos versiones inferiores a la 8) en tu archivo `RouteServiceProvider` existe una propiedad cuyo valor es el string que apunta a Controllers entonces la invocación puede quedar de esta forma:

   ```
   Route::get('sacar/{codigo}','bodegaController@sacar')->name('sacar');
   ```
3. Por otro lado y como puedes [corroborar en la doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-action) la sintaxis del helper `action` va de esta forma:

   ```
   action('bodegaController@sacar', ["codigo" => $bodegas->codigo])
   ```

   Donde:

   - Los parámetros de la ruta se pasan en forma de array asociativo
4. Finalmente si a la ruta la estás nombrando, entonces creo que sería mas simple apoyarse del [helper route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-route) de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   {{ route('sacar', ["codigo" => $bodejas->codigo]) }}
   ```

   Donde:

   - El primer argumento es el name que le diste a la ruta
   - El segundo es un array asociativo con el valor dinámico

Comment: Hola, si estuve analizando y como dices la solucion era el valor a retornar `sacar/{codigo}`  lo estaba haciendo de la forma en la que trabaja el edit ya que es basicamente lo mismo por eso no se lo colocaba pero me imagino que edit por ser una funcion propia no es necesario ya que se da por entender que espera un valor. Muchas gracias por el aporte :)